# How to get the thumbnail image for multi-selected files

Tags: .net, windows, uwp, windows-runtime

I can get the thumbnail image for a single file using **StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync** Method. Is there a way to get a thumbnail for multiple file selections?  Similar to the one that is displayed in Window's Explorer when multi-selected files are dragged? [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd2J7.png)

Comment: Currently, we can get the thumbnail image for a single file, but there is no method to get a thumbnail for multiple files directly . Why do you want to get a thumbnail for multiple files? Can you show more details about your expected behavior?

Comment: I need to show a file group in UWP, if the group only has one file, I will show the file's thumbnail, if there are multiple files in the group, I would like to show something representing the multiple files, similar to Window's Explorer  shows when multi-selected files are dragged.

Comment: There is no direct method to get a thumbnail for multiple files, if you want to achieve it, maybe you could create an ItemsControl as thumbnail, then put images into ItemsControl and bind its Source with the thumbnail you get from each file. After that, change the margin of each item from ItemsControl to achieve superimposed effect.